# API Call Button Not Functioning On First Click or Two

Tags: lightning-web-components, api, address

I am currently working on a simple project for a client that wants a tool to calculate the rates they will charge for shipping. It takes two user-input address, makes a distance matrix API call on them, and then multiplies the resulting time by the hourly rate to arrive at a final shipping cost. It works, except that you have to push the button which actually makes the API call once, twice or sometimes three times before it shows any numbers.

I've search around for similar issues but haven't found anything relevant. Here is the code; can anyone shed some light on what might be happening?

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

   export default class FreightRateCalcv1 extends LightningElement {


       key = 'myAPIKey'
       originAddress = '1234 Main Street, Chicago, IL';
       destinationAddress = '2345 South Street, Springfield, IL';



       totalTravelTime; // given in seconds from API 
       totalTravelMinutes; //totalTravelTime / 60
       freightRateHourly = 120; //Default is 120. User can change. 
       freightRateMinutes = 2; //freightRateHourly / 60
       rateTotal;

       handleOriginAddress(evt){
           this.originAddress = evt.detail.value;
       }

       handleDestinationAddress(evt){
           this.destinationAddress = evt.detail.value;
       }

       handleFreightChange(evt){
           this.freightRateHourly = evt.detail.value;
       }

       getDriveTimes(originAddress,destinationAddress){
           var requestOptions = {
               method: 'GET',
               redirect: 'follow'
             };
             
           fetch('https://distancematrixapi.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' + originAddress + '&destinations=' + destinationAddress + '&key=' + this.key, requestOptions)
               .then(response => response.json())
               .then(data => {
                   this.totalTravelTime = parseInt(data.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value)})
               .catch(error => console.log('error', error)); 

               this.totalTravelMinutes = ((this.totalTravelTime)/60)
           
       }
                   
       getTotal(){
           this.getDriveTimes(this.originAddress,this.destinationAddress);
           console.log((this.totalTravelMinutes));

           this.freightRateMinutes = ((this.freightRateHourly)/60).toFixed(2);

           this.rateTotal = (this.freightRateMinutes * this.totalTravelMinutes).toFixed(2);

           console.log("$"+this.rateTotal);

       }
}
```

Comment: you would need to debug the lwc using your browsers dev tools to identify the cause, find out if the button is actually invoking the function every time or not, check if the request is retuning any errors and which ones, etc, etc.

Comment: The solution to this ended up being that I had to use an async/await structure for my API call. I simply added "await" being my fetch request after marking the function as asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the variables were set before a response was recorded from the API. By using an await/async structure, I was able to get this to function. I changed my API call to this strucutre:

```
async getDriveTimes(originAddress,destinationAddress){
           var requestOptions = {
               method: 'GET',
             };
             
           await fetch('https://distancematrixapi.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' + originAddress + '&destinations=' + destinationAddress + '&key=' + this.key, requestOptions)
               .then(response => response.json())
               .then(data => {
                   this.totalTravelTime = parseInt(data.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value)})
               .catch(error => console.log('error', error)); 

               this.totalTravelMinutes = ((this.totalTravelTime)/60)
           
       }
```